# How do the performance characteristics of jQuery selectors differ from those of CSS selectors?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I came across Google's Page Speed add-on for Firebug yesterday. [The page](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rendering.html) about using efficient CSS selectors said to not use overqualified selectors, i.e. use `#foo` instead of `div#foo`. I thought the latter would be faster but Google's saying otherwise, and who am I to go against that?

So that got me wondering if the same applied to jQuery selectors. [This page](https://www.adaptavist.com/display/~gfraser/2008/01/12/Some+quick+tips+for+jQuery+performance) I found the link to on SO says I should use `$("div#foo")`, which is what I was doing all along, since I thought that things would speed up by limiting the selector to match `div` elements only. But is it really better than writing `$("#foo")` like Google's saying for CSS selectors, or do CSS versus jQuery element matching work in different ways and I should stick with `$("div#foo")`?

Comment: Wouldn't this also depend on the browser?  I.E.: Google chrome puts a strong emphasis on Javascript processing.

Comment: That's not relevant. Sure, different browsers execute Javascript at different speeds. What I wanted to find out, however, was which method had a more favourable time complexity, where the speed of execution in different browsers has no relevance whatsoever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$("#foo")` is better than `$("div#foo")`

Since id is unique in the document you don't have to prefix it with a tag name.

Here is a nice link

[jQuery Performance Rules](http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/)

Comment: Thanks. So it's #foo instead of div#foo. The page also mentions using div.foo instead of just .foo. Does it apply to CSS as well then?

Answer (score 1):

The Sizzle Selector Engine parses selectors right to left.

Use IDs as much as you can to enhance performance.

Answer (score 1):

The more specific the selector is, the faster Sizzle (jQuery's selector engine) finds that object.

Reason: `getElementsByTagName` is used to narrow the search down to a few cases.

But this doesn't apply on unique id-names!